# C Socket Programming with CygWin

Tags: c, sockets, cygwin

Hi
I'm trying to write a little server / client program in C using CygWin, problem is, the gcc compiler in Cygwin doesn't seem to contain the standard headers assosiated with socket-programming. When trying to compile my server program, i get:

```
netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
netdb.h: No such file or directory
```

Are these three headers located elsewhere in the CygWin-enviorment?

Comment: They don't show up under `/usr/include`?

Comment: yes, they are where they're supposed to be, under /usr/include/sys, netinet... but compiler doesnt find them?

Comment: Try reinstalling the compiler, it's clearly a broken install.

Answer (score 2):

I also had same problem.. i was googling for hours and finally found this... thanks to ralph...

https://ralphexe.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/run-unix-socket-program-in-windows-using-cygwin/

For socket commands you have to include some of the packages in cygwin while installing...
(If you have installed try reinstalling ...)

During the installation :

1. In  "SELECT PACKAGES " phase of installation.
2. Expand DEVEL
3. select GNU compilers for c and c++

   4.And click next and complete the installation.

[image]

NOW, try with a socket program involving sys/socket.h ... 
I HOPE IT WILL WORK ...  :-)..

Answer (score 1):

Try using the -I compiler command line option to specify a path to the header files.

My local reference states

```
-I dir
       Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for
       header files.  Directories named by -I are searched before the
       standard system include directories.  If the directory dir is a
       standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure
       that the default search order for system directories and the
       special treatment of system headers are not defeated .
```

Answer (score 0):

At least on my cygwim they are in

/usr/include/sys and /usr/include/netinet

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.
I've resolved to review the compile options.

NG:

```
$ gcc -mno-cygwin -o echo_server.exe echo_server.c
echo_server.c:12:43: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
echo_server.c:13:24: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
```

OK:

```
$ gcc -o echo_server.exe echo_server.c
```

Answer (score 0):

*I had this problem for days with the library apophenia .
so make sure the libraries you've installed have first been configured with a simple command*

**./configure**

*once configured use the following commands to build , Install and check the libraries*

**all**- Builds libraries

**install**- installs libraries

**check**-tests the libraries

**doc**- generate documentation via doxygen

*Hope it helps. :)*