# Libraries not found in Cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin

When trying to compile this program:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("Hey there\n");
    return 0;
}
```

i get compiler-error:

```
test.c:1:24: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
test.c:2:24: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory
test.c:3:19: netdb.h: No such file or directory
```

I use Cygwin (in Windows). Seems the compiler doesnt find any of the libraries exept a few core ones (stdio, string..., stdlib also works...). Is this a linking issue or does it have something to do with my installation of Cygwin? Do i have to specify that i want these libraries included when installing Cygwin? Please help, i'm dying here...

Comment: Yes, cygwin only comes with the most basic stuff. You'll need to install those if cygwin even has an option to do that.

Comment: No, not Linux, cygwin packages. Linux would do though.

Comment: Duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162237/c-socket-programming-with-cygwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to run cygwin's setup.exe again, and find the packages that contain the headers you need. Maybe there's a unix net package somewhere.

Comment: According to http://cygwin.com/packages/cygwin/cygwin-1.7.7-1 these headers are part of the core "cygwin" package itself.  It should literally be impossible to install Cygwin without them.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try MingW (http://www.mingw.org).

Comment: That won't help.  MinGW is a toolchain for Win32 programming; it certainly doesn't provide the UNIX sockets API that Awy's code requires.